# Build 32 bit libcurl on 64 bit OSX

Tags: c++, macos, curl, makefile, libcurl

I am trying to build a 32 bit lib of [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) for OSX, on a 64 bit OSX installation (Yosemite 10.10.5), according to [the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html). I've tried calling ./configure with a number of different arguments, but this is the one that I would expect to cover all bases:

```
CFLAGS='-m32 -arch i386' LDFLAGS='-arch i386' ./configure --host=i386-apple
```

I've tried different hosts as well, such as x86-apple, x86-apple-darwin, i386-apple-darwin, etc. They all build without issues, as far as I can see, but when I try to build my other 32 bit project that links to the resultant dylib, I get the following error message

```
warning: ignoring file [...]/libcurl.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

And then several variations on

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_curl_easy_cleanup" [...]
```

A call to

```
lipo -info libcurl.a
```

Yields the following result

```
fatal error: [...]/lipo: archive with no architecture specification: libcurl.a
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my ./configure call badly formed, am I missing a flag or an argument? According to the [installation instructions](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html), people have successfully compiled to i386 Mac OS X, so I'm assuming there's something I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late, but since I just hit the same wall... You can try specifying in configure options:

```
./configure --build=i386-darwin --host=x86_64-darwin
```

As far as I can tell, `host` denotes the architecture of the machine on which you are building, while `build` is the target architecture.